# Ucercontrol in datatemplate all objects are automaticly "shared"

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datatemplate, tabcontrol

So I got a tabcontrol that is bound to an list(has name and code). And this is working perfectly

```xml
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <sp:ucercontroltest  DataContext="{Binding}"  strname="{Binding Path=name}" strcode="{Binding Path=code}"  />
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

But if I would add a Button(btntestbutton) on usercontroltest with an event, that if the button is clicked I want the button to be disabled (btntestbutton.IsEnabled = false) then it gets disabled on ALL the usercontrols(tabs)! How can I prevent it from all being shared wich each other so If I for example want to disable the button on 1 usercontrol so that I don t automaticly disable all of them.

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding}"` is pretty redundant by the way.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yep 200 %, I got a listview on the ucercontrol, and I want all the ucercontrols in each tab to have a different listview items. the listview items are created with the code String that gets passed, however each string is different but once I load the string and make it a list, then put the list in the listview, if I switch tab the listview stays the same(but if on that tap I create List of items that gets insirted in the listview then it changes) but then it will still be the same on all tabs.

Comment: @H.B. without that, the name and code String won t get passed. ^^ I dunno why: /.

Comment: @Maximc: Oh, then your `ucercontroltest` is setting the `DataContext` internally (which it should not do!).

Comment: @H.B. oke ty I removed the inside binding now it is not more needed to put the datacontext there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know `TabControls` reuse the controls created from the `ContentTemplate`, one way to have a state unique to the tabs would be to bind the `IsEnabled` property of the button to a property on the VM of each tab, then the state would adjust on tab-switch. (Of course you then would need to adjust the VM property in the handler, not the `IsEnabled`)

Comment: This is correct.... WPF will re-use templates when possible and simply replace the `DataContext` behind the Template to switch the current item

Comment: @Rachel: Indeed, "when possible". If the `TabControl.ItemTemplate` is set explicity that is always the case of course.

Comment: I don t use a VM :'( ? (Is this realy bad :p ?)

Comment: @Maximc: Oh noes, i have been infected by MVVM, throwing those terms around. It does not really matter (while you should have some model-view-separation pattern), a view-model would lend itself to this as a buttons state does not exactly belong into the model though.

Comment: @H.B. Could you provide me perhaps with a good example how to make a VM of a class. When I google about MVVM(Which I've done many times) I get loads of guides that are 10 pages long with , all grey text even the code, more words then code etc. Btw isn t there an other way to make tabs, mayby without the contenttemplate but with something else? I am thinking now of going to add Tabs dynamicly by c# code. But I would perfere to only use XAML.(Because I am unexpierienced with it +- and want to learn with it! :))
Anyway ty already for all the info.

Comment: @Maximc: MVVM is not easy, you have to get through at least some of that to understand the principles and architecture, this really is not the place for me to explain this to you. There are many tutorials and if you want something really simple check out [this presentation by Jason Dolinger](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650). Also try to use MVVM in a small test project first to see if you got it right, then move to whatever it is you are really working on.

Comment: @H.B. Oke ty I ll watch the tutorial later! Ty for the video, much easier for me to learn(Video vs Text tutorials) :). Btw can t I just make the controltemplate of the tabcontroller "static" or something so each template is different?